# Under what circumstances does Scrapy throw a "Connection was closed cleanly" error?

Tags: python, scrapy

While running a crawler on a site, I'm getting the following error message a large number of times:

```
<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>
```

I don't get this error when running the crawler on different sites, and the pages it's trying to access I can reach either via browser or via `curl`. Thus, I'm wondering what situations might cause this error to arise?

To clarify, the full error is something along the lines of:

```
2016-11-17 20:59:38 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.peets.com/gifts/featured-gifts/holiday-gifts/sheng-puer-tea-50.html>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
```

There are many different urls that produce a similar error, and likewise it doesn't *always* fail if I run it multiple times. So I'm unclear what `ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly` should imply in terms of what the problem was.

Comment: What the HTTP response says ?

Comment: Scrapy is not reporting the HTTP response: its only saying `ERROR: error downloading <GET (some url)>: (above error)`.

Comment: If you are using Windows, I would use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check what's happening.

Comment: This is running on an unix box.

Comment: Then on *nix try [mtimproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/), it will show you every HTTP request and response.

Answer (score 4):

Today I had the same error. I think those websites have Crawler preventions.
If I add:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0'
```

in `settings.py` it solves the error.